# how to make a swing hinge rig

Tags: rigging

hello guys does anyone know how to make a rig to make swing hinge like this? https://www.dropbox.com/s/bdj4bj9rcqxoy7e/window.mp4?dl=0

here i tried with damped track, i added two with 1.000 and 0.000 of head/tail influence, but still is not convincing the rig...
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I made the swing system with IK constraint.

[image]

### Creation procedure

Creation of arm system proceeded as follows:
Step 1: Simple arm system (Armature)
Step 2: Design drawing (Mesh)
Step 3: Basic arm system (Armature)

[image]

#### Step 1

[image]

[image]

#### Step 2

[image]

#### Step 3

[image]

Bone (Controller): Limit Rotation
Bone.002: IK constraint
Bone.003: Copy Rotation and Transformation

The Transformation constraint was used to absorb the bone length matching error. It is very difficult to exactly match the bone length a + b = c + d.

#### Appendix

With offset between Bone and Bone.003 length.

[image]

Comment: can you provide the blend file perhaps please?

Comment: Ok, I've done it.

Comment: @tetti check this file, maybe you can try to improve this rig to be accurate as possible https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-0_XSdkzt3cbRstBiiuESUoZh92EQ2Dx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't physically work with the mesh objects.I'll upload a working example later.